# How to make Indivdual array results, into links?

Tags: php, php-5.4

I am trying to return an array of results from php, and each result is a link. When a link is clicked, it will go into another php that echo the details that are related to link/array clicked. But i am not very sure how to do that. What i attached below is the array echoed out. 
Please any thoughts would be good. Thanks for your time.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);


include 'connect.php';
$username=$_SESSION['username'];


$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Listing WHERE username = '$username'")or die( mysqli_error($con));
$solutions = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {

          print $solutions[0]=$row['Listingname']."</br>";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i know what you mean. 
That when you have this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{    
   echo '<a href="/names/'.$row['Listingname'].'">'.$row['Listingname'].'</br>';
}
```

That you get a list of names as a **link**. 
**Alfredo** *(www.MySite.com/names/Alfredo)* 
**Sandra** *(www.MySite.com/names/Sandra)*

And somebody clicks on a link, like Sandra. He goes to the url:

> www.MySite.com/names/Sandra

And on that page, you can get the url with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

```
$parts = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
$name = $parts['4'];
```

Example of the query can be:

```
"SELECT * FROM Names WHERE name = '$name'"
```

And than you can get the results from the url into the query to get the results of the name. That you can show on the page.

Comment: Thanks man! Yer similar but a little different, all the links link to 1 php and within that php that result will be used as $_session[name], then draw out all the other info from the row. If you get what i mean?

Comment: Oke, no problem! Happy to help, i see your answer ;)

Comment: But just 1 more question, would i be able to $_SESSION an array as individually? example I pull a row from 'name', Peter, Ben, John, the 3 names are link, and would i be able to $_SESSION those 3 names with something similar to $_SESSION[name]['']?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, i built up on your answer and got what i needed.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);


include 'connect.php';
$username=$_SESSION['username'];


$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Listing WHERE username = '$username'")or die( mysqli_error($con));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {

          echo '<a href="SpecificListing.php">'.$row['Listingname'].'</br>';
        }
}



?>
```